# Copying a file from Debian to Windows 8 using Samba is really slow

Tags: windows-8, debian, samba

I've been running a simple Debian Wheezy server (CubieTruck 3) for a while now and since a couple of days the transfer speeds between my desktop (Windows 8) and the server are really slow (`50kb/s - 300kb/s`). It has been working fine for over 2 months and it started getting slow 3 days ago.

Download speed (`wget --output-document=/dev/null http://speedtest.wdc01.softlayer.com/downloads/test500.zip`) returns `8.38MB/s` and it's about `8MB/s` on my desktop too (same file downloaded via Google Chrome), and speedtest.net is measuring `90Mb/s`.

Things I tried already:

- Replaced both LAN cables (cat6),
- smb.conf: `socket options = TCP_NODELAY IPTOS_LOWDELAY SO_SNDBUF=8192 SO_RCVBUF=8192`,
- Restarted server and desktop multiple times,
- Problem is also occuring on my laptop (WiFi)

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It could be your router.  One of two things comes to mind, it's open and being abused by neighbors or the router needs to be replaced/upgraded.

Log on to the wifi router and see who is connected.  Make sure it is just your
devices!

Restart the wifi router and see if that fixes it.

If not might be time to get a new one and secure it well with WPA2, a long password and don't broadcast the SSID to help keep the neighbors out ;)